# z-index for caption div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with creating 2 elements with different `z-index`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.capty.css">
<script src="jquery.capty.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-jesse.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-jesse.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.fix').capty({
        cWrapper: 'capty-tile',
        height: 36,
        opacity: .6
      });

      $('#list').jesse();

    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #list {
      max-width: 640px;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }

    div.capty-caption {
        z-index: 999;
    }

  </style>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="jq-jesse" id="list">
    <li class="jq-jesse__item">
      <a href='http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/coloring_medium/public/cif/2015/10/number-1-coloring-page.png' target='_blank'><img class="fix" name="#content-target-1" src='http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/coloring_medium/public/cif/2015/10/number-1-coloring-page.png' width='100' height='100'></a>
      <div id="content-target-1">
        <a href="#">[x]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="jq-jesse__item">
      <a href='http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/coloring_medium/public/cif/2015/10/number-2-coloring-page.png' target='_blank'><img class="fix" name="#content-target-2" src='http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/coloring_medium/public/cif/2015/10/number-2-coloring-page.png' width='100' height='100'></a>
      <div id="content-target-2">
        <a href="#">[x]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8HSgSbc96LlSQ66hgY79?p=info

How can I intercept a click on the caption?
I'm trying to set `z-index: 999` for div `capty-caption`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Comment: j08691, all code in fiddle

Comment: I understand that, however your code should always be in your question and never solely located on another website where we have to go to view it. What if that site is blocked, down, or inaccessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you are looking for is well described in [Simple jQuery Plugin For Drag & Drop Sorting Of Lists - jesse](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Sorting-Of-Lists-jesse.html)

```
$('#list').jesse({
   // executed when the item has dropped
   onStop: function(position, prevPosition, item) {
      alert('ok');
   }
});
```

The onStop is executed at the end of mouseup event. If you do not need this but only the click event you may always use (I discourage you to follow this path):

```
$('#list').mouseup(function(e) {
   alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: No, it is not.This is event for drag. I need event for click on hover caption.

Comment: @stdex click or mouseup events  have both the same effect from user point of view. Have you tried my suggestions?

Comment: thanks for help, I can use: `$('.capty-caption').mouseup(function(e) { alert('ok'); });` for intercept click on caption.